# 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token' - why sent token is NULL

Tags: php, android, flutter

I tried to build an app in Flutter on Android.
There is `'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'` HTTP header sent from `readData()` method. The problem is that `$token` is not sent properly and Null is received on the server.
I tried to send `$token`, `${token}`, plain text token (String) - none worked.

When I tried sending get request containing token as a plain text from https://reqbin.com/post-online it worked fine.

Could you please advice on what causes the issue?

```
  Future readData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = prefs.getString('token').toString();

    print('Token : $token');     // prints $token OK

    final response = await get(
        Uri.parse('https://www.somehost.com/api.php'),
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',     // here token is null (read from server log)
        }
      );

    print(response.statusCode);

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    print(data);
    print(data['success']);
    print(data['user']['email']);
  }
```

and API code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

require __DIR__.'/classes/db.php';
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

$allHeaders = getallheaders();
$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();
$auth = new Auth($conn, $allHeaders);

echo json_encode($auth->isValid());
?>
```

Comment: """final response = await get( """ pls add detailsa bout get method used in this line.

Comment: I changed as you wrote and still get the same issue:I/flutter (13731): 200
I/flutter (13731): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (13731): stdClass Object
I/flutter (13731): ^

Comment: Unexpected character means parsing issue. log and check the response

Comment: in php logs on the server I got the same error message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #1 ($jwt) must be of type string, null given, called in ...

Comment: I checked API code and it gets NULL while sending get request from android.

Comment: Can you connect in room for better understanding of your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255453/discussion-between-bzc0fq-and-prashant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing, where the token is not being sent properly and is received as null on the server, may be related to how you're retrieving the token from SharedPreferences in Flutter.

Your code for retrieving the token from SharedPreferences looks fine:

```
String token = prefs.getString('token').toString();
```

However, the problem might occur if there is no token stored in SharedPreferences or if the stored token is not being retrieved correctly.

Here are some steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Check Token in SharedPreferences: First, make sure that you have saved the token correctly in SharedPreferences at some earlier point in your app. Verify that the token is being saved with the key 'token' and that it's not null at that point.

Print Token Value: Before making the HTTP request, print the value of token to the console to verify that it's being retrieved correctly from SharedPreferences.

```
print('Token : $token');
```

If this print statement shows the token correctly, it means that it's being retrieved from SharedPreferences as expected.

HTTP Request Header: The way you are using the token in the Authorization header looks correct:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
```

Ensure that the token is not empty or null at this point. You can print it to verify.

Check Token in Request: You can add some debugging code on the server side to inspect the actual headers received by the server. Log the headers to see if the Authorization header contains the token. For example:

```
$token = isset($allHeaders['Authorization']) ? $allHeaders['Authorization'] : 'No token provided';
error_log('Received Token: ' . $token);
```

This will help you determine if the token is actually being sent from the client to the server.

API Endpoints: Double-check that the API endpoint 'https://www.somehost.com/api.php' is the correct endpoint and that it expects the Authorization header in the format you are providing.

CORS Issues: Ensure that there are no CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues preventing the request from being processed correctly. The headers you've set on the server side should allow requests from any origin ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *").

By carefully checking these points and verifying the token at various stages (from storage to retrieval to the request), you should be able to identify and resolve the issue causing the token to be null on the server side.

Comment: I checked error_log and token is received exactly as sent - means OK.  I get this error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(): Argument #1 ($jwt) must be of type string, null given, called in /classes/JwtHandler.php on line 51 and defined in /vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:95

Comment: OK...  it works now... All I did was following your troubleshooting way and making sure everything was set as you described

Comment: probably I did not save the changes last time.... Anyway.. thanks for helping! :)

Comment: @bzc0fq sorry man i didn't check your reply glad it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String token = await prefs.getString('token');
```

instead of

```
String token = prefs.getString('token').toString();
```

as prefs.getString() returns a Future, so need to add await.

Comment: it does not change anything since $token is OK..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add await as if you do not add the print command you wrote and the API call will be triggered together so that is why you are seeing the token been printed as well with the correct value but the API is already called. Using await makes sure that you receive the token first and then only calls the API. So i agree with MSC you need that to work

```
String token = await prefs.getString('token');
```